# Exception Handling: stuck in infinite loop if a char is entered

Tags: c++, exception

I'm having a problem with my exception handling. It seems to work with negative input, but whenever I try to enter a character, it gets stuck in an infinite loop in the first `try/catch` block.

I try `clear()` and `ignore()` for `cin`, but it still didn't work. I tried a different `if` statement for input, such as `(if ((ft >100)) || (in >100))`, and the exception is thrown just fine.

Am I missing something?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class convert
{
private:
    int feet;
    int inch;
public:
    convert() = default;
    double calculation(int ft, int in)
    {
        double cm = 0;

        cm = ((ft * 30.48) + (in * 2.54));

        return cm;
    }
};

class negativeNumber
{};

class invalidInput
{};

int main()
{
    int ft;
    int in;
    double cm = 0;
    convert h;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            cout << "Please enter your height in (ft, in) format" << endl;
            cin >> ft;
            cin >> in;

            if ((ft < 0) || (in < 0))
            {
                throw negativeNumber();
            }
            if (cin.fail())
            {
                throw invalidInput();
            }
            cm = h.calculation(ft, in);
            cout << "Your height in cm is: " << cm << endl;
            break;
        }
        catch (negativeNumber)
        {
            cout << "You entered negative numbers. Try again" << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
        catch (invalidInput)
        {
            cout << "You entered a character. Try again" << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in `cm = ((ft * 30.48) + (in * 2.54));`, you don't need any of those parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need to call `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` when input fails to read. You need to clear `cin`'s error state in order to continue reading input, and you need to remove the failed data from `cin`'s input buffer so you don't keep reading the same data over and over.

Also, you should check for input failure *before* checking for negatives. `ft` and `in` will not have valid values if they fail to read.

Also, you should always catch exceptions by (`const`) reference, not by value.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

class convert
{
public:
    static double calculation(int ft, int in)
    {
        double cm = 0;
        cm = ((ft * 30.48) + (in * 2.54));
        return cm;
    }
};

class negativeNumber
{};

class invalidInput
{};

int main()
{
    int ft;
    int in;
    double cm;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            cout << "Please enter your height in (ft, in) format" << endl;
            if (!(cin >> ft >> in))
            {
                throw invalidInput();
            }

            if ((ft < 0) || (in < 0))
            {
                throw negativeNumber();
            }

            cm = convert::calculation(ft, in);
            cout << "Your height in cm is: " << cm << endl;
            break;
        }
        catch (const negativeNumber &)
        {
            cout << "You entered a negative number. Try again" << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
        catch (const invalidInput &)
        {
            cout << "You entered bad input. Try again" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```